# Cannot import Flask-FlatPages

Tags: python, deployment, flask, server

I'm new here and this is my first question.

I finished a flask project which uses flatpages.

I have this line of python import code at the beginning

```
from flask_flatpages import FlatPages
```

It works well for local test. When I deploy it on server, it doesn't work.
I have install those modules by pip. Actually I can run this command in the command line of server, which proves that I have already configured it correctly.

However, when I visit the the domain, it keeps saying "500 internal server error".
I'm sure that this "500 internal server error" is caused by this line of code, because the website works well only if I remove this line.

Any idea about this?  I have spent a whole day on this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You did not say anything about your deployment, but just a guess: your server does not run in your virtual environment.

Comment: It runs in virtual environment, because the terminal's prompt shows the virtualenv name obviously. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Look into the logs of your wsgi server.